# Accessing data in dataframe based on dates in r

Tags: r

I have this mesurements from my temperature sensor that I put in a dataframe `data`.

```
           Time          Temperature
1  2012-06-28 12:49:00       23.04
2  2012-06-28 12:49:34       23.06
3  2012-06-28 12:49:38       23.06
4  2012-06-28 12:49:39       23.08
5  2012-06-28 12:49:40       23.08
6  2012-06-28 12:49:56       23.09
7  2012-06-28 13:49:00       23.02
8  2012-06-28 14:49:00       22.73
9  2012-06-28 15:49:00       22.50
10 2012-06-28 16:49:00       22.38
11 2012-06-28 17:49:00       22.31
12 2012-06-28 18:49:00       22.16
13 2012-06-28 19:49:00       22.11
14 2012-06-28 20:49:00       22.04
15 2012-06-28 21:49:00       21.89
16 2012-06-28 22:49:00       21.78
17 2012-06-28 23:49:00       21.66
18 2012-06-29 00:49:00       21.64
19 2012-06-29 01:49:00       21.52
20 2012-06-29 02:49:00       21.42
21 2012-06-29 03:49:00       21.36
22 2012-06-29 04:49:00       21.34
23 2012-06-29 05:49:00       21.24
24 2012-06-29 06:49:00       21.29
25 2012-06-29 07:27:08       21.32
26 2012-06-29 07:49:00       21.38
27 2012-06-29 08:49:00       21.39
28 2012-06-29 09:49:00       21.44
29 2012-06-29 10:49:00       21.42
30 2012-06-29 11:49:00       21.58
31 2012-06-29 12:49:00       21.96
32 2012-06-29 13:49:00       22.22
33 2012-06-29 14:49:00       22.33
34 2012-06-29 15:49:00       22.51
```

The type of data in `data$Temps` are `POSIxlt`

I want to create a new dataframe that includes only the mesurement of for exemple this day : 2012-06-28. That would be `data[1:17,]`

I tried to work with the function `which()` based on exemples from the internet but I failed to find a solution.

What function should I use ?

Comment: You can use the `date` function from `lubridate` package to filter on specific dates (i.e. without the hour-minute-second elements).

Comment: `split(data,date(data$Time))` splits your `data.frame` into a list of `data.frames` with one element for each day.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that i used this :

```
library(lubridate)
data[date(data$Time)==ymd("2012-06-28"),]
```

It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as.Date`

```
subset(data, as.Date(Time) == as.Date("2012-06-28"))
```